# how to get customised ceil and floor value for a given variable?

Tags: javascript

I want customized ceil and floor using javascript. Here for ex: if the particular floating point variable 10.1 then I need the result as 10 (floor) if the value is more than 10.1 then I need to make it 11 (ceil). here 10 would be variable. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: if the decimal part is > `0.1` use `Math.ceil()` else `Math.floor()`?

Comment: yes, if xx.10 then xx, if xx.20 then xx+1

Comment: `const toVal = (val) => val - Math.floor(val) > 0.1 ? Math.ceil(val) : Math.floor(val)`

Comment: `Math.round(thing + 0.4);`

Comment: Math.round(thing + 0.3); works fine

Comment: @VLAZ how would it not work?

Comment: @epascarello argh, I misread it...yeah, should work.

Comment: If it were `thing=10.11` if would not @VLAZ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way:

```
Math.round(thing + 0.4);
```

Say thing = 2.11, then you’re rounding 2.51 = 3. If thing = 2.09, you round 2.49 = 2.  Should work!

Comment: Um, this is wrong. `Math.round(10.1 + 0.4) === 11` not `10` like OP said

Comment: OK, after re-analysing this I realised I was wrong but it's still wrong. As @epascarello says, it fails for `10.1`. If we change the constant that's added to `0.39`, then it works for `10.1` but fails for `10.101`. And with each `9` added to the end of the constant, it fails for another order of magnitude down in an input value -> `0.399` and `10.1001`. Well, unless floating point arithmetic messes this *up* but still.

Comment: @epascarello Yep since the question edit this is no longer correct

Comment: Not sure what Edit, the revision history shows someone corrected English unless there was an edit before the time cut off. I love ninja edits...

Answer (score 3):

Better to do it with Math instead of adding a decimal. Subtract the whole number, check the remainder, update the whole number if greater than .1 and return it.

```js
function customRound (num) {
  let wn = Math.floor(num)
  let adj = num - wn > .1 ? 1 : 0
  return wn + adj
}

console.log('10.1', customRound(10.1))
console.log('10.11', customRound(10.11))
console.log('10.01', customRound(10.1))
console.log('10.100000000001', customRound(10.100000000001))
```